# How to configure different logback.xml in storm-project?

Tags: java, logback, apache-storm

Consider that I hava a storm cluster that runs two Topologies (A and B), but I just change the `${storm_dir}/logback/cluster.xml` in supervisor machines, so A and B are using the same log configurations, how to configure the `logback.xml` in different project instead of changing it in storm-cluser? I am worried about that

Comment: AFAIK there is no vanilla way to do so. But maybe someone rolled his own solution for that?

Comment: Considering https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-184, I doubt there is an easy way to do it as of right now

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to official documentation no other ways there. The logs are configured only in the *$STORM_HOME/logback/cluster.xml* (since 0.9). The main problem is that *logviewer* daemon depends on that file to be able to find and display worker logs. Overriding it would break the log viewer functionality.

Personally in your case you can separate your topologies by the different packages. It's allow you configure loggers for your topologies in the similar way:

```
<logger name="com.example.topology.A">
    <level level="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE_A"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
</logger>

<logger name="com.example.topology.B">
    <level level="WARN"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE_B"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
</logger>
```

So, you can specify different logger level and appender for different topologies just change *cluster.xml* file.

Comment: That is an obvious solution but it only solves part of the problem of course - it's only your own custom logging in your own topology classes that gets steered towards FILE_A and FILE_B. Say they both call hibernate functions and you want that internal hibernate logging, then you would either have to log all hibernate logging into both files, or into a third file. Both are workable but neither are nice. Any smart ideas on that?